# Question about element in $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and its product with its permutation: $\sum_{j=1}^nj\sigma(j)$ for $\sigma \in S_n$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory

Let $\sigma\in S_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  I am interested in $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^nj\sigma(j)$.  Can anyone help point me in a decent direction?  If $\sigma = (1)$ in cycle notation, we have that the sum just becomes $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.  Now for the fun part, I actually want to look at this sum for all of the permutations in $S_n$.  We can brute force this for small $n$, but it quickly gets out of hand.

Comment: An interesting fact you can see using orthogonal transformations is that the value for $\sigma$ is the same as for $\sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: "want to look at this sum for all of the permutations" - please clarify.  Do you mean the sum you wrote, taking $\sigma$ to be *any specified* permutation?  Or do you mean the sum of that sum over *all* permutations,$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\sum_{j=1}^n j\sigma(j)\ ?$$

Comment: I am actually looking at what happens when you $\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} a^{\sum_{j=1}^nj\sigma(j)}$

Comment: please edit the question with the proper formulation. It may be closed for not having sufficient detail, but it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you mean the sum over all $\sigma$ of the sum you wrote.  (If you meant you want to investigate the sum you wrote for specific individual $\sigma$, that's different.)

So... reversing the sum,
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\sum_{j=1}^n j\sigma(j)=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} j\sigma(j)\ .$$
The inner sum has $n!$ terms, and among those terms, each value $\sigma(j)=1,2,\ldots,n$ occurs $(n-1)!$ times.  So
$$\eqalign{\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} j\sigma(j)
  &=\sum_{j=1}^nj(1+2+\cdots+n)(n-1)!\cr
  &=(1+2+\cdots+n)^2(n-1)!\cr
  &=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}(n-1)!\ .\cr}$$

Comment: What if $\sigma$ was chosen at random uniformly? What would be the expected value of $$\sum_{j=1}^nj\sigma (j)?$$

Comment: Would it just be the sum in your answer, over $n$?

Comment: @Shaun over $n!$, so $n(n+1)^2/4$.

Comment: +1 but the OP clarifies in a comment that they are looking for $\sum_\sigma a^{\sum \dots}$, where this trick doesn't seem to work as simply.

Comment: Thanks @ronno.  I asked for clarification, didn't receive a reply for a while so decided to answer anyway.  Note to OP - at least this will show that in order to work out other things, you don't *necessarily* need to work out the original sum over $j$.

Comment: No that's still helpful for other things as well.  I appreciate it!